# How to segue with AlertView?

Tags: swift, segue, alert, uialertview

This is the code for the alert. The problem is that I want to segue to another VC when the user press the button "Ja" which means "Yes" In english.

```
@IBAction func TillbakaAction(_ sender: UIButton)
{
     createAlert(title: "Är du säker på att du vill börja om?", message: "Ifyllda betyg nollställs")


}
func createAlert (title:String, message:String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //CREATING ON BUTTON
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ja", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print ("Jag vill gå tillbaka")



                }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Nej", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Nej, jag vill inte gå tillbaka")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call `dismiss` with alert it will automatically dismiss the alert when you press any action of `AlertController`.

So simply add `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` with your action.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ja", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

    print ("Jag vill gå tillbaka")
    // call the segue at hare
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"SegueIdentifer", sender: nil)
}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Nej", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

    print("Nej, jag vill inte gå tillbaka")
}))

self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: What would I do without you. Thanks

Comment: @theswed Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func TillbakaAction(_ sender: UIButton)
{
     createAlert(title: "Är du säker på att du vill börja om?", message: "Ifyllda betyg nollställs")


}
func createAlert (title:String, message:String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //CREATING ON BUTTON
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ja", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print ("Jag vill gå tillbaka")
// call the segue at hare


                }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Nej", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Nej, jag vill inte gå tillbaka")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```